# Why my form parameters not getting in JSP

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, servlets

This is my HTML form :

```
 <form action="supplierportal_home.jsp">


   <select id="contract" name="contract"> 
     <option    selected="selected">Please Select</option>
     <option    value="open" >Open</option>
     <option    value="limited" >Limited</option>  
   </select>

   <input type="text" name="cpv_code" placeholder="<%= cpvOrTenderNo %>">

   <button type="submit">FIND  <%= contractOrTender %></button>

  </form>
```

And i am getting in JSP

```
String  contract=request.getParameter("contract");
    System.out.println("%%%"+contract);

    String  cpv_code=request.getParameter("cpv_code");
    System.out.println("%%%"+cpv_code);
```

Here is the problem.Seems very nasty.

When I enter both the values then only `parameters` getting in `jsp`  If I select only the contract from options then `null` is coming  if i give cpv-code then  the parameter is coming ...can any one please help to get out this ...

Why my select option values are depending on the other form element `cpv-code` value,please show some cause for this.

Thanks.

Comment: try to debug by putting all the code in comment and remove line by line

Comment: Please format the HTML code.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot Done !! can you please tell me now whats the issue ?

Comment: Hmm its strange , I'm not getting any such issue . I ran it in Tomcat 7.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot Not even on container.I am facing in Eclipse it self.Why this ?? If i entered in textbox then only  the first one value coming in jsp if i change only drop down value and submit the form that value is coming null...  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button type="submit">FIND  <%= contractOrTender %></button>
```

In this example whenever you will enter text in textbox then only **contractOrTender** 
this value can be objtain from textbox.

But as you not entering any value in textbox and trying to access value from dropdown it will come 'null' only. as boz at this time **<%= contractOrTender %>** this value is null.

which an error in jsp page. thats why you not getting dropdown value even if you dont enter any value in textbox.

***Solution***

Try to set some default value to textbox.  or

change your HTML code.

Comment: Nope.I removed all those jsp scriplets and tried ..nothing happened.Eroju I am booked.

Comment: so now your code looks like this??
 <form action="supplierportal_home.jsp">


   <select id="contract" name="contract"> 
     <option    selected="selected">Please Select</option>
     <option    value="open" >Open</option>
     <option    value="limited" >Limited</option>  
   </select>

   <input type="text" name="cpv_code">

   <button type="submit"></button>

  </form>

Comment: Yes exactly ..Still facing the same issue.Seems like some environment issue,as Chris said.

Comment: The code works fine at my end.
i think tomcat server issue might be there.

Comment: Yeah..There is no clue left with me.That was really strange.. :(.Thanks for the support.

Comment: I did'nt get the issue and finally set some space value in text box and as of now i am got ridoff this.chala thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have just tested the code and it seems to work fine. No value is depending on the other. Only suggestion is add `method="POST"` if you don't want the data to be sent over URL.

**index.jsp**:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Index Page</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="upload.jsp" method="POST">


   <select id="contract" name="contract"> 
     <option    selected="selected">Please Select</option>
     <option    value="open" >Open</option>
     <option    value="limited" >Limited</option>  
   </select>

   <input type="text" name="cpv_code" />
   <button type="submit">FIND</button>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**upload.jsp**:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Upload JSP</title>
</head>
<body>

<%
String  contract=request.getParameter("contract");
System.out.println("%%%"+contract);

String  cpv_code=request.getParameter("cpv_code");
System.out.println("%%%"+cpv_code);
%>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try the code that I just pasted and let me know if it works. If it doesn't, it could be an environment issue

Comment: haahh..No.May be the environment issue.Still the same issue exists.

Comment: All I can say is this code works perfectly (as expected). Can you deploy your war in a freshly downloaded standalone tomcat and try it out of your eclipse ? Also, if you need more help you need to provide more information. May be a simple project on github where the problem is reproducible